# Definition of $L^p(\mathbb T)$ with $\mathbb T$ the unit circle

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, lp-spaces

I'm trying to define the $L^p$ spaces in the unit circle(denoted as $\mathbb T$), as Rudin's Real and Complex analysis does in page 88. I've defined a measure in $\mathbb T$ via Riesz's representation theorem, with the functional $\Lambda f=(1/{2\pi})\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(e^{it})dt$ (Lebesgue measure) and I'm trying to prove that there's a correspondence between $2\pi$-periodic functions in $\mathbb{R}$ and functions in $\mathbb T$ that preserves measurability.

I've already proved that if $F\colon\mathbb T\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is measurable , then the function $f(t)=F(e^{it})$ is periodic and measurable (Lebesgue). But the converse seems a bit tricky, because the inverse (as a function) of $e^{it}$ is not continuous , and that is the important part of the identification.

Sorry for my bad english and thanks in advance!

Comment: How is $e^{-it}$ not continuous?

Comment: But the inverse of $e^{it}$ is not $e^{-it}$ .

Comment: This doesn't really work; let $f \equiv 1$, then $f\notin L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic, but $if(t) \equiv 1$ and since $\mathbb{T}$ is compact, $if \in L^p(\mathbb T)$. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Then what do you mean by "inverse"?

Comment: sorry, inverse function. Because $e^{it} $ is a function from $(-\pi,\pi]$ to $T$ that is bijective and continuous. But the inverse is not continuous, since $T$ is compact but  $(-\pi,\pi]$ is not. And i want the periodic function to be measurable, not $L^p$ integrable. And the function $f=1$ is measurable.

Comment: Alright, then chose $\mathbb T \leftrightarrow \mathbb R / 2\pi \mathbb Z$, this is in fact compact, and the embedding is continuous again (It can be identified with the $2\pi$-periodic continuation of your original inverse $\mathbb T \to (-\pi, \pi]$)

Comment: But then you can only use this with the continuous functions, to get the continuous extensions in $T$. How do you get measurability?

Comment: By continuity of the restriction Operator
$$R: L_{2\pi}(\mathbb R) \to L((-\pi, \pi]) (\stackrel{\text{incl.}}{\to} L(\mathbb T))$$
$$Rf := \left. f \right|_{(-\pi,\pi]}$$

Comment: The inverse map is Borel. To prove this, it is enough to show that the direct image of any interval by the exponential map is a Borel subset of $\mathbb T$; which is obvious.